# PHP email script having trouble

Tags: php

Emailing fine the variables are not getting filled. I get all the email but the email is empty, other than the subject but that is the concatenation. PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>

Thank you! <?php echo($_POST["name"]); ?><br>
<a href="http://sagethesite.comuv.com">Back</a>

<?php
// get var
$body = $_POST["comment"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = "Name: " . $name . " Email: " . $email;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$body = wordwrap($body,70);

//Convert to plain text
$body = strip_tags($body);

// send email
mail("sage@sagethesite.comuv.com" ,$subject , $body);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Form code:

```
<form action="emailhandle.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name"><br>
    E-mail:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="your email"><br>
    Comment:
    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form> <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: You need a few tweaks to send mail from localhost,assuming that`s the case.

Comment: You have numerous errors in this code.

Comment: It's not from localhost the href attribute is the website.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure that the email address is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = "New comment";

// the message

$body = $_POST["comment"];

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters

$body = wordwrap($body,70);


//Convert to plain text

$body = strip_tags($body);

// send email

$name = $_POST["name"]; //assuming the field is entitled "name"

$to = $name." <sage@sagethewebsite.com>";

mail($to ,$subject, $body);
```

Comment: Your e-mail address was invalid, you should also convert the message to plain text since you're not including any message headers.  You also should define a subject.  Take a look at my re-worked code and see if that goes through for you.

Comment: Thanks I'm recieving the emails now. They are empty though no text or anything.

Comment: How is $comment being populated?

Comment: Yeah I was just looking into that. It wasn't

Comment: I revised my code to populate that body variable on the assumption the field name is comment and its a POST

Comment: one more thing how would i concatenate the name and email string

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a8019008/public_html/emailhandle.php on line 15

Comment: line 15: $body = wordwrap($body,70);

Comment: Please post emailhandle.php so I can what line 15 is.

Comment: The error is most likely on the previous line, make sure your line is terminated (has a ; at the end)

Comment: So post isn't working. That is why the emails are blank.

Comment: What is the method of your form set to?

Comment: I revised my question

Comment: This all looks correct to me, you can enumerate all the fields and data being posted by performing print_r($_POST) and it will show you everything in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jason you have been a huge help. I decided to just change it to GET and it now works perfectly. You have been a tremendous help.

I still don't know why the post didn't work. But the only reason I cared was to learn about it and it would look nicer.

Anyways thanks a lot.